# Bug in std::regex?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Here is code :

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string pattern("[^c]ei");
    pattern = "[[:alpha:]]*" + pattern + "[[:alpha:]]*";
    std::regex r(pattern); 
    std::smatch results;   
    std::string test_str = "cei";

    if (std::regex_search(test_str, results, r)) 
        std::cout << results.str() << std::endl;      

    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
cei
```

The compiler used is `gcc 4.9.1`.

I'm a newbie learning regular expression.I expected nothing should be output,since `"cei"` doesn't match the pattern here. Am I doing it right? What's the problem?

**Update:**

This one has been reported and confirmed as a bug, for detail please visit here :
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63497

Comment: @Vajura: `[[:alpha:]]` should be a correct character class. It is mentioned in the C++ reference as an extension to ECMA script.

Comment: Aside from problems with your code, Regex support in current gcc is very limited. Imho, it's not worth the trouble. Use Boost's Regex and be happy. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2014

Comment: Removing the first `[[:alpha:]]*` gives the expected result, I'm not sure what the conflict is.

Comment: Just some info: on gcc 4.8.x it throws `std::regex_error` at line `std::regex r(pattern);`

Comment: clang++ works (libc++), gcc fails (stdlibc++) ... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc56ed8c533bda55

Comment: thx @rubberboots I'm gonna try `boost` instead.

Comment: @Alan.W `[[:alpha:]]*` will eat up all characters. Then, there's no `cei`left for the matcher because it's already at the end. With backtracking, the string should match ....

Comment: :S I thought it was an invalid/bad regex.. https://www.myregextester.com/index.php  it doesn't work on there..  using `[A-Za-z]*[^c]ei[A-Za-z]*`  even on http://regex101.com/ and regexpal, it doesn't work.. so..  Even using just `[^c]ei` it fails.

Comment: @Niall I tried Clang++ 3.4, it complained like crazy..Should I use 3.5 instead?

Comment: @Alan.W, yes, I believe the coliru clang is 3.5.0.

Comment: @rubberboots: If you read the tables carefully on the link you posted, GCC claims to have full C++11 regex support.

Comment: This seems to be a bug related to the fixed string optimization, where the engine searches for the fixed string first before evaluating the rest of the expression.

Comment: The correct pattern is: `(?!c)ei` aka negative lookahead.. I don't understand how all of you guys are deeming this a bug.. His pattern doesn't work in Java. It doesn't work anywhere even if you replace the `[[:alpha:]]` with `[A-Za-z]`  http://ideone.com/ksbtAq

Comment: @Brandon: Your pattern will always match `ei`. The pattern in the question is a valid pattern according to C++ standard, and the correct behavior is that it won't match `cei`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck correct, they changed that feature list compared to what I read some time ago. Maybe I'll give it another trial in depth ... Thanks!

Comment: @Alan.W IMHO Learning Regex w/C++ libraries is too hard and too obfuscating due to the C++ionisms in style and expression. I'd like to advice you to use Perl for regular expression learning and gradually transferring working expressions into C++ later. See this book: http://regex.info/

Comment: @rubberboots Thx man! I do hear that `perl` is pretty good for using regex, but I have no experience on `perl`. Do you think it's still a better choice even without any experience on `perl`? I was told that `perl` is a quite strange language..

Comment: @Alan.W - TO Perl OR NOT TO Perl? This is clearly a question of your capabilities and learning time resources. In order to find out, you could spend one evening at this: http://learn.perl.org/

Comment: @rubberboots Awesome! I'll try it. `Perl` sounds pretty cool anyway.Thx again.

Comment: @Alan.W http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in the implementation.  Not only do a couple other tools I tried agree that your pattern does not match your input, but I tried this:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string pattern("([a-z]*)([a-z])(e)(i)([a-z]*)");
  std::regex r(pattern);
  std::smatch results;
  std::string test_str = "cei";

  if (std::regex_search(test_str, results, r))
  {
    std::cout << results.str() << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
      std::ssub_match sub_match = results[i];
      std::string sub_match_str = sub_match.str();
      std::cout << i << ": " << sub_match_str << '\n';
    }
  }
}
```

This is basically similar to what you had, but I replaced `[:alpha:]` with `[a-z]` for simplicity, and I also temporarily replaced `[^c]` with `[a-z]` because that seems to make it work correctly.  Here's what it prints (GCC 4.9.0 on Linux x86-64):

```
cei
0: cei
1:
2: c
3: e
4: i
5:
```

If I replace `[a-z]` where you had `[^c]` and just put `f` there instead, it correctly says the pattern doesn't match.  But if I use `[^c]` like you did:

```
std::string pattern("([a-z]*)([^c])(e)(i)([a-z]*)");
```

Then I get this output:

```
cei
0: cei
1: cei
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_create
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So it claims to match successfully, and results[0] is "cei" which is expected.  Then, results[1] is "cei" also, which I guess might be OK.  But then results[2] crashes, because it tries to construct a `std::string` of length `18446744073709551614` with begin=nullptr.  And that giant number is exactly `2^64 - 2`, aka `std::string::npos - 1` (on my system).

So I think there is an off-by-one error somewhere, and the impact can be much more than just a spurious regex match--it can crash at runtime.

Comment: Since you are mentioning a crash `".{0,3}[^\\s\\S]ei.?"`

Comment: Thx man! I got exactly the same thing using your code.I guess I need `Clang` or use `boost` instead.

Comment: @Alan.W: or just formulate your regex a bit differently.  Several expressions I tried which were not too much different than this worked as expected.  Do you want to file a GCC bug for this?  I think you should.

Comment: Cool I'll try different pattern. Bug reporting? Can I? How to report such thing? Can you share a link or something that I can learn how to report this bug?

Comment: @Alan.W: here you go: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gcc - you will need to create an account.  It's easy enough, don't be scared.  :)

Comment: I found `Bug 61720` is quite similar : https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61720. Can you have a look? Should I still report this bug?

Comment: @Alan.W: I think you should report it.  Worst case one fix will correct both bugs; your expressions are a bit different from the other one, plus we have demonstrated that it results in an outright runtime crash which should not be possible as far as I can tell.  Please do file a bug and link it in a comment here.

Comment: Done,it's Bug 63497 : https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63497 Is it ok? If anything I wrote is not appropriate, please let me know.

Comment: @Alan.W: looks good to me (not that my opinion matters in this case!).  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The regex **is** correct and should **not** match the string "cei".

The regex can be tested and explained best in Perl:

```
 my $regex = qr{                 # start regular expression
                 [[:alpha:]]*    # 0 or any number of alpha chars
                 [^c]            # followed by NOT-c character
                 ei              # followed by e and i characters
                 [[:alpha:]]*    # followed by 0 or any number of alpha chars    
               }x;               # end + declare 'x' mode (ignore whitespace)

 print "xei" =~ /$regex/ ? "match\n" : "no match\n";
 print "cei" =~ /$regex/ ? "match\n" : "no match\n";
```

The regex will first consume all chars to the end of the string (`[[:alpha:]]*`), then **backtrack** to find the NON-c char `[^c]` and proceed with the e and i matches (by backtracking another time).

Result:

```
 "xei"  -->  match
 "cei"  -->  no match
```

for obvious reasons. Any discrepancies to this in various C++ libraries and testing tools are the problem of the implementation there, imho.