# GCC has problems with \d in std::regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, gcc

I have the following regular expression object that I create:

```
std::regex magStripe{R"(^%B(\d+)\^)"};
```

([Full, working sample here](http://ideone.com/qFAbWc))

When this regex object is constructed, `std::regex_error` is thrown with code set to 2, which happens to be `std::regex_constants::error_escape`. I did some process of elimination and when I remove the `\d`, it works just fine.

I tested this on VS 2013 and it does not throw an exception. I [tested this on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/faadec2c1faccb58) and it seems to completely crash. If I use clang++ it works.

Why isn't this regex working on GCC? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which version of GCC exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure what version. If you look at the first link, on ideone.com it just says "C++11". Locally on my machine, I'm using GCC 4.8 from Android NDK r10 which also fails.

Comment: I get the same compiler error without the \d.

Comment: `GCC 4.8` is known, to be buggy about [regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex), and incomplete support.

Comment: Thanks; for now I've switched to `boost::regex` until it is working again. It appears GCC 4.9 fixes this problem: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html -- it is currently available in Android NDK r10c

Comment: gcc 4.9 is still buggy the last time I see a question on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272592/bug-in-stdregex), it affects even the latest version 4.9.1. I suggest that you stay away from it for a while.